# Flutter web | WebView Flutter | No reproduce contenido en la web

Tags: html, flutter, webview, jwplayer

Tengo el siguiente codigo en flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'WebView',
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: HomeScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }

  HomeScreen() {
    var src='https://sfntv.xyz/ver/cn';
    WebViewController webViewController=WebViewController();
    WebViewWidget webViewWidget=WebViewWidget(controller: webViewController);

    webViewController.loadRequest(Uri.parse(src));
    return webViewWidget;
  }
}
```

estoy usando la dependencia de WebView Flutter para cargar la página que se muestra en el codigo. Pero al intentar reproducir contenido en la pagina al cargar un canal X lanza un error en el reproductor.
Sin embargo, si abrimos esta pagina en un navegador chrome comun y corriente, veremos que el contenido se reproduce sin problemas.

El error en el reproductor es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se debe esto?

Busque por todo internet y no encontré una solucion aun, e probado otros paquetes de visualizacion de webs para flutter pero no me han funcionado.

Espero sus respuestas amigos. gracias !

Comment: él código que has puesto es el que estás usando? Qué error te lanza?

Comment: Así es , el mismo código.